# Helper Class en Modelo

Tags: c#, xamarin

Hola tengo una clase modelo de un objeto que recibo de una api, pero tambien necesito aplicar algunos cambios a los valores segun el caso, originalmente estaba heredando a la clase las interfaces.

Pero mi jefe em esta pidiendo que mueva eso a una helper class, alguien sabe como puedo usar una Helper class en mi modelo de forma propia??

Intente esto no puedo accesar a las props de MOPDTO

```
 public class HelperDTO : INotifyPropertyChanged, IFormattable
    {
      
        public string ToString(string format, IFormatProvider formatProvider)
        {
            switch (format)
            {
                case "ExpirationDate":
                    string expirationformat = "";
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ExpirationDate))
                    {
                        expirationformat = ExpirationDate;
                        if (ExpirationDate.Length == 3)
                        {
                            expirationformat = ExpirationDate.Insert(1, " / ");
                        }
                        else if (ExpirationDate.Length == 4)
                        {
                            expirationformat = ExpirationDate.Insert(2, " / ");
                        }
                    }
                    return expirationformat;
                case "LastFourCardNumbers":
                    return MaskedMopAccountNumber.ToString().Substring(MaskedMopAccountNumber.Length - 4);
                default: return "";
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public class MopDTO : HelperDTO
    {
        public const string EXPIRATION_DATE_FORMAT = "MMyy";
        public const string TYPE_VISA = "Visa";
        public const string TYPE_MASTERCARD = "Mastercard";
        public const string TYPE_DISCOVER = "Discover";
        public const string TYPE_AMEX = "American Express";
        public const string TYPE_CHECKING = "Checking";
        public const string TYPE_SAVINGS = "Savings";
        public const string TYPE_UNKNOWN = "Unknown";
        private string _mopAccountType;

        [JsonProperty("mopId")]
        public string MopId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nameOnCard")]
        public string NameOnCard { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("mopType")]
        public MOPMigratedType MOPMigratedType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("mopAccountType")]
        public string MopAccountType
        {
            private get => _mopAccountType;
            set
            {
                _mopAccountType = value;
                MopType = ConvertMopAccountTypeStringToMopType(_mopAccountType);
            }
        }

        [JsonProperty("maskedMopAccountNumber")]
        public string MaskedMopAccountNumber { get; set; }


        [JsonProperty("expirationDate")]
        public string ExpirationDate { get; set; }

        private bool _enrolledInAutoPay;  
        [JsonProperty("enrolledInAutoPay")]
        public bool EnrolledInAutoPay
        {
            get => _enrolledInAutoPay;
            set
            {
                 _enrolledInAutoPay = value;
                 
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EnrolledInAutoPay));
            }
        }

        [JsonProperty("scheduledFdps")]
        public List<string> ScheduledFdps { get; set; }

        public bool IsNew { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the MopType based on the MopAccountType.
        /// </summary>
        /// <value>The MopType.</value>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Making this setter public will make it collide with json value for
        /// mopType and fail to deserialize!
        /// </remarks>
        public MopType MopType { get; private set; }

        #region Helper Methods
        public static MopType ConvertMopAccountTypeStringToMopType(string mopAccountType)
        {
            switch (mopAccountType)
            {
                case TYPE_VISA:
                    return MopType.Visa;
                case TYPE_AMEX:
                    return MopType.AmericanExpress;
                case TYPE_DISCOVER:
                    return MopType.Discover;
                case TYPE_MASTERCARD:
                    return MopType.Mastercard;
                case TYPE_CHECKING:
                    return MopType.PersonalChecking;
                case TYPE_SAVINGS:
                    return MopType.Savings;
                default:
                    return MopType.Unknown;
            }
        }

        public static string ConvertMopTypeToMopAccountTypeString(MopType mopType)
        {
            switch (mopType)
            {
                case MopType.Visa:
                    return TYPE_VISA;
                case MopType.AmericanExpress:
                    return TYPE_AMEX;
                case MopType.Discover:
                    return TYPE_DISCOVER;
                case MopType.Mastercard:
                    return TYPE_MASTERCARD;
                case MopType.PersonalChecking:
                    return TYPE_CHECKING;
                case MopType.Savings:
                    return TYPE_SAVINGS;
                default:
                    return TYPE_UNKNOWN;
            }
        }

        #endregion Helper Methods
    }
```

Comment: a que "props" no pudiste acceder? y desde donde?

Comment: MaskedMopAccountNumber y ExpirationDate

Comment: Porque queres acceder desde el padre a las propiedades del hijo?